# Print PDF file to network POS printer using PHP

Tags: php, printing, pos

The pdf file can print to the POS printer directly in windows.
How to print the pdf file by php?

I tried
1/

```
$lpr = new PrintSendLPR();
$lpr->setHost($printerip);
$lpr->setData($filename);
echo $lpr->printJob("someQueue");
```

it can print successfully to a normal printer with A4 size but nothing in POS printer.

2/

```
$conn = fsockopen($printerip,9100,$errno,$errstr)  
fputs($conn, file_get_contents($filename), filesize($filename));
```

it print out asc code rather than the pdf content

3/and I found the printipp, but I have no idea on what is the $printerurl

```
$ipp = new PrintIPP();                        
$ipp->setHost($printerip);
$ipp->setPrinterURI($printerurl);
```

Thanks,

Comment: With all the codes you've shown us you are addressing the POS printer directly. It is highly unlikely that a POS printer is capable of understanding, and printing, a PDF file, which is basically PostScript. It might be able to print images, when given the correct commands. You could convert a PDF to an image, with PHP, and send that to the printer. But only if you can find out how to print an image, and even that won't be easy.

Comment: The big question that hangs over your question is: Which POS printer are you using?

Comment: Thanks KIKO, you enlighten me! is that Imagick can make it easy or some other advice?! The printer is not a popular brand but it doesn't restricted on only using their software for printing.

Comment: You can find code online to convert a PDF to an image. It can be done, but it is not an easy process. As I said before, this is completely useless unless you can find out how to print an image with the POS printer you have. So I would start with solving that problem first. Most printers need special instructions to print an image, and these codes vary from printer to printer. That's why you have a printer driver in Windows.

Comment: Is this library famous? [mike42/escpos-php](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php) Is it possible to print if the image matches the size of the paper and print range of the printer? [graphics(EscposImage $image, $size)](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php#graphicsescposimage-image-size)

Comment: Thanks kunif, mike42's project is great, but it bring me another problem that I'm still running php5.5. do you have idea to use it!

Comment: Isn't PHP 5.5 supporting up to the previous version(v2.2)? [Releases - mike42/escpos-php](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/releases)

Comment: Thanks kunif, ethernet.php can print txt to printer. but where should I put the ip address in the real example script such as demo.php

Comment: I put the ip into NetworkPrintConnector($ip) on demo.php, but it doesn't work,,, your advice would be highly appreciate!!

Comment: That seems like a new issue, so why not ask a new question on this site or in the mike42/escpos-php repository? Or would you try searching for Issues in the mike42/escpos-php repository before asking a question?

Comment: Thank you very much kunif, just posted a new question. Hopefully there are solution